# How can I remove slider from mobile version rather than just hiding it?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mobile, responsive

I'm trying to remove the slider from our web site on mobile devices. I know I can use the display: none style but this only hides the element which still causes the browser to try and load it, therefore reducing load time. Is there anyway I can use php or jquery to fully remove the web site on mobile devices? TIA.

Comment: Jquery, you can use `$('#your-slider-div-id').remove()` which completely remove div from dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods to do it.
You can use PHP and check if the visitor is using a mobile.
I suggest you to use this library: [Mobile_Detect.php](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/master/Mobile_Detect.php)

And use it with:

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ($detect->isMobile() ) {
  //do something
}
```

Everything here: http://mobiledetect.net/

In alternative you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] with preg_match.